Italic small caps with fontspec?
I've seen various questions about how to get italic small-caps, which suggest e.g. using lmodern and slantsc together.
However, I'm currently using beamer, and want to keep the sans-serif typeface (which doesn't support slantsc) in most places. There are just a few specific spans where I need to distinguish between caps, smallcaps, italic/slanted smallcaps, lowercase, and italic/slanted lowercase. (When transliterating cuneiform, these indicate different categories of signs.)
Presumably with fontspec I could set up Latin Modern or some other font that supports italic/slanted smallcaps, and use that font only for the transliteration passages. But I can't find any documentation on how to make fontspec and slantsc work together.
How can I set up Latin Modern, or any other font, with fontspec so that I can use italic smallcaps with it?
MWE:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{slantsc}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Example}
Normal \textit{Italic} \textsc{Smallcaps} \textsl{\textsc{Slanted Smallcaps}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}

Output:

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/lmss/m/sc' in size <10.95> not available
(Font)              Font shape `TU/lmr/m/sc' tried instead on input line 8.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/lmss/m/scsl' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/lmss/m/sc' instead on input line 8.

(I don't love the difference in font here, but I can live with it if I have to; the distinction between smallcaps and italic/slanted smallcaps is vital, and actually looking nice is less vital.)

You don't need slantsc anymore, current LaTeX directly supports slanted small caps.
For Latin Modern Sans Serif LaTeX already specifies the substitution for small caps to fall back to Latin Modern Roman, you can add a similar rule for the slanted variant:
\documentclass{beamer}

\DeclareFontShape{TU}{lmss}{m}{scsl}
  {<->sub*lmr/m/scsl}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Example}
Normal \textit{Italic} \textsc{Smallcaps} \textsl{\textsc{Slanted Smallcaps}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}



Noto Sans for example
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{Noto Sans}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Example}
Normal \textit{Italic} \textsc{Smallcaps} \textsl{\textsc{Slanted Smallcaps}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}


